# Access subform position

Tags: ms-access

I've run into the Access "problem" where a subform that contains two linked datasheets doesn't show up at all if there's no data.  I tried a suggestion where I have a second subform for new records, and when I open up the parent form, I can check which subform should be visible based on whether there's data or not.

This works, but the problem I have is positioning.  The "data-is-there" subform is not visible, but it still takes up a lot of whitespace on the main form.  The "no-data" subform appears at the bottom.  How can I make it appear in a better position?

Comment: On the subform frame (not on the form itself but the frame that hold the subform) there is a Data tab and one of the property's called "Filter On Empty Master" turn it to No.